# Terminated iOS app due to memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

In my app, i am getting an error (Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue)  and app crashes. I have checked my app by leaks in Xcode instrument but no issue found. please help me to find a solution why this is happening?

[image]

code below shows memory warning..

**code 1**

if (![[[pollOptionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"option_color"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{

```
        NSArray* foo = [[[pollOptionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"option_color"] componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];


        if([[foo objectAtIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"FFFFFF"]||[[foo objectAtIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"ffffff"]){

            [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"000000"]];

        }else{

            [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:[foo objectAtIndex:1]]];

        }


        if([[foo objectAtIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"FFFF00"]||[[foo objectAtIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"ffff00"]){

            [titleLabel setTextColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"000000"]];

        }

        //[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:[foo objectAtIndex:1]]];


        if(votedPoll && [votedPoll valueForKey:@"option_id"] && [[votedPoll valueForKey:@"option_id"] isEqualToString:[[pollOptionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"option_id"]]){

            titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            //titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[self colorWithHexString:[foo objectAtIndex:1]] CGColor];
            titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
            titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 2;
            titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
            titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

            //Blur the image
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(titleLabel.bounds.size.width, titleLabel.bounds.size.height));
            [titleLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIImage *viewImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            //Blur the image

            CIImage *blurImg = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImg.CGImage];

            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
            [clampFilter setValue:blurImg forKey:@"inputImage"];
            [clampFilter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];

            CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
            [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:clampFilter.outputImage forKey: @"inputImage"];
            //[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

            [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];


            CIImage *guesImg=gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage;
            CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

            CGImageRef cgImg = [context createCGImage:guesImg fromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,70,40)];
            UIImage *outputImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];

            //Add UIImageView to current view.

            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(titleLabel.frame.origin.x-10, titleLabel.frame.origin.y,titleLabel.frame.size.width, titleLabel.frame.size.height)];


            //imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"arrow.png"];

            [imgView setTag:1109];

            imgView.image = outputImg;
            [imgView setTag:1108];

            gaussianBlurFilter = nil;
            outputImg = nil;
            blurImg = nil;

            viewImg = nil;
            [titleLabel addSubview:imgView];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;


        }else{

            blurImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
    }
```

**code 2**

if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theModal.noPercentage] isEqualToString:@""] ||[theModal.noPercentage isEqual: [NSNull null]])
    {
    self.lblNoPercentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ %@ ",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theModal.noPercentage],@"%",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theModal.btn2Name] ];

```
    if([theModal.btn2Color isEqualToString:@"FFFFFF"]||[theModal.btn2Color isEqualToString:@"ffffff"]){

        [self.lblNoPercentage setTextColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"000000"]];

    }
    else{

        [self.lblNoPercentage setTextColor:[self colorWithHexString:theModal.btn2Color]];

    }


    //[self.lblNoPercentage setTextColor:[self colorWithHexString:theModal.btn2Color]];
    CGRect frame = self.btn4label.frame;
    frame.origin.x= 228;
    frame.origin.y= 74;
    frame.size.width= 100;

    [self.btn4label setFrame: frame];


}
```

**code 3**

-(void)drawAnnotations
{

```
arrayIndex = 0;
NSArray *pointsArray = [self.mapVIEW overlays];
[self.mapVIEW removeOverlays:pointsArray];


for(int i = 0; i<pollListArr.count ; i++)
{

 MKPointAnnotation *annotation  = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    PollListHomeModal *themodal = [pollListArr objectAtIndex:i ];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([themodal.poll_latitude doubleValue], [themodal.poll_longitude doubleValue]);
    [self.mapVIEW addAnnotation:annotation];
    annotation = nil;
}
```

}

Comment: Need to find which code produces leak. Could you please share your code where you think most suspected codes.

Comment: Your app can allocate more memory than the system can handle without producing leaks. You have to reduce the memory usage of your app.

Comment: @HwanghoKim edited the question with code.

Comment: @Palle please tell me how to reduce the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release for CGImageRef and need to cover this with @autoreleasepool

I added

```
@autoreleasepool
```

and

```
CGImageRelease(cgImg);
cgImg = nil;
guesImg = nil;
```

I fixed this. Please try and share your result.

```
if(votedPoll && [votedPoll valueForKey:@"option_id"] && [[votedPoll valueForKey:@"option_id"] isEqualToString:[[pollOptionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"option_id"]]){

    @autoreleasepool {
        titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        //titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[self colorWithHexString:[foo objectAtIndex:1]] CGColor];
        titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
        titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 2;
        titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
        titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

        //Blur the image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(titleLabel.bounds.size.width, titleLabel.bounds.size.height));
        [titleLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //Blur the image

        CIImage *blurImg = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImg.CGImage];

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
        [clampFilter setValue:blurImg forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [clampFilter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];

        CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
        [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:clampFilter.outputImage forKey: @"inputImage"];
        //[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

        [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];


        CIImage *guesImg=gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage;
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

        CGImageRef cgImg = [context createCGImage:guesImg fromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,70,40)];
        UIImage *outputImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];

        //Add UIImageView to current view.

        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(titleLabel.frame.origin.x-10, titleLabel.frame.origin.y,titleLabel.frame.size.width, titleLabel.frame.size.height)];


        //imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"arrow.png"];

        [imgView setTag:1109];

        imgView.image = outputImg;
        [imgView setTag:1108];

        gaussianBlurFilter = nil;
        outputImg = nil;
        blurImg = nil;

        viewImg = nil;
        [titleLabel addSubview:imgView];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        CGImageRelease(cgImg);
        cgImg = nil;
        guesImg = nil;
    }
}else{

    blurImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

and

```
arrayIndex = 0;
NSArray *pointsArray = [self.mapVIEW overlays];
[self.mapVIEW removeOverlays:pointsArray];

pointsArray = nil;

for(int i = 0; i<pollListArr.count ; i++)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation  = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        PollListHomeModal *themodal = [pollListArr objectAtIndex:i ];
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([themodal.poll_latitude doubleValue], [themodal.poll_longitude doubleValue]);
        [self.mapVIEW addAnnotation:annotation];
        annotation = nil;
        themodal = nil;
    }
}
```

Please test it. I can't found any suspected code for 2

Comment: thanks Hwangho Kim. but the warning appear in 2 more code can you please look in to it.